# Create mysql tables dynamically based on a criteria in ruby on rails 5

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am new to Rails and I am trying to create a web app where you scrape some html from a page and store it into a database in order to compare it to a different version e.g the price of a product changed. The way I want to make it work is to create a new table every time you scrape something from a domain that's new.

So basically every domain has its own table for changes. I know how to create tables with migrations but how do you dynamically create a table when a new domain is added ?

Comment: You don't want a table per domain, that violates relational design principles. Instead put everything in one table with a column indicating domain source.

Comment: Would't that create a very inefficient database for comparing changes from the same domain if for example the pages are scraped every few hours and stored in the same table ?

Comment: That's what indexes are for. They make it easy to search through a subset of the data for whatever you want. You'll also want to hash the content you get so you can skip duplicated inserts. If the content hash matches, ignore it, don't save it, as you already have a snapshot of that version.

Comment: Cheers for the quick replies and advice, I will use just one table as you suggested and hash the data.

Comment: You'll be pleasantly surprised how much data a simple database can sponge up and still perform well. When you do have problems with scale, consider using [partitions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html) to manage things. Going down the multiple table road gives you quick wins ("yay, less data per table!") but soon proves to be completely unmanageable ("it crashes my SQL client when I list all databases").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended "relational database" way to do this is to have a singular table and relate that table to the source. For page snapshots you can often hash the content to test for duplicated data, and a `UNIQUE` index on your content hash can automatically prevent those sorts of inserts.

If portions of the page update but you're not interested in them, like advertising blocks, you can use a tool like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) to pre-process and strip out that content before hashing and saving.

Now if this is just part of a pipeline where you're capturing pages with the express intent of extracting price information later, you may not need a database at all for that part of the process. You could funnel the raw page data into a queue like [RabbitMQ](http://rabbitmq.com) and have workers process it, boiling it down to the price data, which is all you insert in the database.

If you need to preserve the page snapshots for diagnostic or historical reasons then a table will work. To save on size you can explore using an [ARCHIVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/archive-storage-engine.html) type table. These are append-only, you can't edit them, but they are compact and perform well.

You could periodically `TRUNCATE` a table of that sort to clear out old data so you're not keeping junk around forever.

Comment: Thanks, I am already using Nokogiri and I will read more about ARCHIVE tables as I want to keep the records.